# Are there stocks dynamic that cannot be represented by Generalized Black Scholes model?

Tags: black-scholes, martingale, dynamic

The generalized Black Scholes Model refers to a stock dynamic that satisfy

$$
dS(t)=S(t)(\mu_t dt+ \sigma_t dW(t))
$$

By martingale representation theorem, it seems that if there is a risk neutral probability measure, then all stock dynamic is enclosed by the GBS.

Are there exceptions?

Comment: This model doesn’t include jumps in the asset price

Comment: @KeSchn I think using, for example Dirac delta function in the $\mu_t$ can get around the theoretical stock price decrease during dividend payment

Comment: Can you capture autocorrelation in $\sigma_tdW(t)$?

Comment: I was more thinking about something like Merton's (1976) or Bates' (1996) model where you add a Poisson process as additional risk source. So you have jumps at random times with random jump size.

Comment: @KeSchn the problem you point out here is that $\mu_t dt$ has no random component right? At least, that's not clear from the notation.

Comment: @BobJansen You're right, we would need $\mu_t=\mu(t,S_t)$ and $\sigma_t=\sigma(t,S_t)$. The latter would allow for the autocorrelation/stochastic volatility features you mentioned. If one includes a Dirac delta function in the mean though, that may affect integrability conditions and existence of solutions? The integral over $\mu_t$ would then only be $\mu_t$ evaluated at the mass point of the DD function. But the model certainly does not allow for standard jump processes such as Merton or Kou.

Comment: @KeSchn Indeed, I may have missed some parts of the notation, I should also include the stochastic part. However, What I meant is something like $\mu_t=( \mu +\delta_s (t)/S(t))$ where s is the time when a 1 dollar dividend is paid per unit stock

Comment: If you want to be general, you’ll have to allow for jumps regardless of dividends.

Comment: And to be _really_ (but pointlessly) general, you have to allow for a stochastic dividend process. And allow for jumps in that dividend process, and make the parameters of that jump process random etc. etc. etc. So, one can easily write down more complicated/general models. But they are of course not useful. A good point to start are SVJ and SVJJ models. As @BobJansen said, you ought to include jumps in the stock price regardless of how you model your dividend payments.

Comment: @KeSchn The reason that I asked the question is that if there were a way to prove every stock dynamic is modeled by GBSM, then by Girsanov theorem there will be a way to generate a risk-neutral probability measure.

Comment: The existence of a risk-neutral probability depends on whether the market allows for arbitrage or not. If it doesn't (which is a reasonable assumption for the big, liquid markets), then you can estimate the risk-neutral probability using a set of observed option price (Breeden Litztenberger (1978)).

Answer (score 3):

KeSchn and I pointed out in the comments that this it is not possible to represent all stock dynamics using the Generalized Black Scholes model. For example, there can be jumps at random moments and not just at random moments but also jumps of random size. These jumps can affect either $\mu_t$ or $\sigma_t$. Models with too many sources of randomness are not considered useful but at least 2 extra source can be useful.

What does this say about the Martingale Representation Theorom. Doesn't that claim that stock dynamics can be captured using an Itô process? Unfortunately, the theorem is a bit more narrow ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_representation_theorem)):

> The martingale representation theorem states that a random variable that is measurable with respect to *the filtration generated by a Brownian motion* can be written in terms of an Itô integral *with respect to this Brownian motion*.

Emphasis mine. As long if there is one Brownian motion driving the randomness, all is good. The theorem doesn't hold with more sources than one.